# RedBus ticket booking API integration in php

Tags: php, api, integration

one of my client asked me to integrate Red Bus API in his website...i am not sure if the RedBus is providing their API for integration. 
If anyone have idea about this API and how to integrate it, i would be glad to here it.

Comment: You contact redbus by mail or toll free contact numbers provided in their site

Comment: did you find any solution to get access to RedBus api??

Answer (score 0):

**RedBus Webservice**

This is a good option if they have one. But looking at their portal they haven’t mentioned about their API/Webservice publicly. So digged in further and came up with couple of their Webservices (they allowed google to crawl into their WSDL)

1) http://www.redbus.in/WS2/BookingService.asmx?WSDL

**CancelTentativeBooking** 
API to cancel the given tentative booking reference number.

**ConfirmTicket** 
API to give confirm the tentatively booked ticket

**DoTentativeBooking** 
API to book a ticket tentatively.This ticket may be confirmed after the payment is made. Here the seats are blocked only for a specified time after which then cannot be confirmed.

**GetAvailableRoutes** 
API to give the list of routes going from the specified source city to the destination city and seats available on the specified date.

**GetBoardingPoints** 
API to give the list of boarding points , times,lcation,address,contactnumber and location for the specified route

**GetDroppingPoints** 
API to give the list of dropping points , times,lcation,address,contactnumber and location for the specified route

**GetRouteDetails** 
API to give the route details for the specified route

**GetSeatLayout** 
API to give the seat layout for the specified route

**TicketRequest** 
API to take ticket request for the specified route and DateofJourney

2) http://www.redbus.in/WS2/LocationInformationService.asmx?WSDL

**GetAllCities** 
API to give all the list of cities along with their city ids.

**GetAllOperators** 
API to give all the list of Operators .

**GetAllSourceDestinationPairs** 
API to give list of all source-destination pairs to which bus services are available.

The above should help you considerably.

Comment: This answer is too old, can any one help with the solutions. the given links are not working.